# Pagination based on page and since_id

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, pagination

We have a table of posts

```
posts(id, title, content, stars)
```

We have a function that receives

- limit: Amount of results
- page: Page to show (default: 1)
- since_id: Restrict results to after the specified ID

How to select posts based on these arguments?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html

```
SELECT
...
LIMIT {perPageLimit} OFFSET {(page - 1) * perPageLimit}
```

Comment: Thanks, what about since_id ?